# Changing an output signal

Tags: analog, control-system, signal-processing, positive-feedback

[image] I need a way for the rotational hall sensor that outputs 0-5v to be centered at 2.5v and if it goes below 2.5v the output rises. If it goes above 2.5v the output adjusts down.
My goal is to have it increase or decrease the output to motor to keep that sensor centered at 2.5v. So if it climbs to 3v and recenters it stays at 3v
The output will be 0-5v.
Hope this made sense

Comment: It doesn't to me, but lets set the question in the sea and see if it sails.

Comment: I think you'll need to describe your concept of "centered" and "recenters" more clearly. What exactly triggers "recentering"?

Comment: Are you pointing a motorized device?  This sounds similar to a solar panel sun tracker.  What voltages are available for the control circuit?

Comment: No there's an arm under spring tension with a roller. A cable wrapping up on a drum hold the arm and roller up. When the arm starts to lift it slows down the motor. When the arm starts to lower it speeds up the motor. The arm position from empty to full drum would shift too much.

Comment: Welcome! Can you draw a graph of how you want the output signal with regards to input? I didn’t fully understand recenter, but a graph would sort that out. Best guess, you need an opamp for scaling and another one for a DC servo.

Comment: If i can figure out how to upload something. lol.

Comment: https://virtual-graph-paper.com/MjA1ZGZhYTQ0YWE0

Comment: Please embed it as an image.

Comment: Thanks. Still hard to grasp though. Perhaps divide it into sections and explain what's happening?

Comment: Simplest description. If it was -5 to +5 input. When input goes positive, output goes negative and stays there until the input goes negative

Comment: The input would be trying to remain at zero by incrementing the output up or down to control a motors speed